# How do I send a modal when a button is clicked?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

Im attempting to send a modal when the "ask" button is clicked from the embed. [image]

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'
```

```
class AskModal(nextcord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            "Ask",
        )
    
        self.emQuestion = nextcord.ui.TextInput(label = "Question", required = True, placeholder = "What level shall I reach to stay in the group?", style = nextcord.TextInputStyle.paragraph)
        self.add_item(self.emQuestion)

    async def callback(self, interaction: nextcord.Interaction) -> None:
        question = self.emQuestion.value
        channel = bot.get_channel(1017234639770894377)
        questionmsg = (f"{question} ^ {interaction.user.id}")
        message = ("Your question has been sent!")

        await channel.send(questionmsg)

        return await interaction.response.send_message(message, ephemeral=True)

class askbutton(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__(
            "AskButton",
        )

    @nextcord.ui.button(label="Ask", style= nextcord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id = "ask button")
    async def asks(self, interaction: nextcord.Interaction, button: nextcord.ui.Button):
        return await interaction.response.send_modal(AskModal())

@bot.command()
async def ask(ctx) :
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title="QNA", description="・You may ask a question by using the slash command `/ask`\n\n・You'll be notified that your question has been answered by receiving a ping in the <#928507764714651698> channel", color= 0x303136)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed, view = askbutton())
```

The ask button doesn't respond when the button is clicked, did I miss something?

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

This is `nextcord`, not `discord.py`. In nextcord the order of the parameters in button callbacks is different.

Discord.py uses `interaction, button`, while nextcord uses `button, interaction`. Swap the order of your parameters.

Your error also suggests this - you're calling `interaction.response` but the error says you called `Button.response`.

**I would consider switching over to `discord.py` instead, though.**

Two official examples side-to-side: [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/confirm.py#L30) - [nextcord](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/blob/v2.2.0/examples/views/confirm.py#L15). If you want to use a fork, make sure to look at the correct docs & examples. You can't mix them across libraries.